# Python: asynchronous tcp socketserver

Tags: python, python-2.7, networking, asynchronous

I'm looking http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html to try and handle asynchronous requests with the socketserver in python. At the very bottom there is an example, but it doesn't make sense. It says you use port 0 which assigns an arbitrary unused port. But how do you know what port to use for the client if they are not in the same program? I do not quite  understand how to make this useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the client is implemented in the same script as the server, the port is known.  In a real-world scenario, you should specify a port for your daemon.  Besides letting your clients know on which port to connect, you may also need to know so that you can open firewalls between your clients and your server.

Answer (score 5):

In the example you linked, they are fetching the port:

```
# Port 0 means to select an arbitrary unused port
HOST, PORT = "localhost", 0

server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
ip, port = server.server_address
```

However, you should really be looking at www.twistedmatrix.com if you are serious about writing async handling :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to retrieve the port that was assigned to the `socketserver` once the `bind` is done: in this case, this will probably be through `ip, port = server.server_address`.

The arbitrary port is just if you want to create a server without specifying a port: the OS will assign an available port.

Of course there must also be a way to specify which port to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

```
server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, 0), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
ip, port = server.server_address

...

client(ip, port, "Hello World 1")
```

The PORT value 0 says "I don't care what port number it is," so the server_address's `port` value is assigned by the ThreadedTCPServer() call.  It is not zero.  Later, you pass that `port` value to the client, who uses it.